# Trim, Left, Right, Mid?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have list of strings in a table that look something like this

```
John Doe 2015 Toyota
Bob Smith 2017 Dodge
Sally Simms 2015 Ford
```

I want to strip off everything before the first instance of a number or two Spaces left of the end. I want to be left with:

```
2015 Toyota
2017 Dodge
2015 Ford
```

I have tried all combination of Left, Right and Mid with variation of Instr and InsrtRev. Can someone please help me with the code for my query. Here is my last attempt and it does not work:

```
Vehicle: Mid([My_Field],InStrRev(InStrRev(1,[My_Field]," ")+1,[My_Field]," "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this modified expression to retract the last two words:

```
Vehicle: Mid([My_Field],1+InStrRev([My_Field]," ",InStrRev([My_Field]," ")-1))
```

To **strip** the last two words:

```
Vehicle: Mid([My_Field],1,InStrRev([My_Field]," ",InStrRev([My_Field]," ")-1)-1)
```

Comment: That did it. That was just what I was trying to do. Thank you so much.

Comment: That line did exactly as I asked. What if I wanted to do just the opposite. Meaning keep everything except the vehicle information. I tried

    'Vehicle: Left([My_Field],InStrRev([My_Field]," ",InStrRev([My_Field]," ")-1))'

but it leaves me with a space at the end of the string and 1- does not work.

Comment: OK. See extended answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is so unpleasant in MS Access.  But something like this should work:

```
select switch(my_field like "* 2*", mid(my_field, instr(my_field, " 2") + 1, 100),
              my_field like "* 1*", mid(my_field, instr(my_field, " 1") + 1, 100),
              my_field like "*  *", mid(my_field, instr(my_field, "  ") + 1, 100),
              1=1, my_field
             )
from t;
```

Comment: I had thought about using switch. But I was hoping there would be some what to use InStr to find the first number(Wildcard). or use InStrRev to look for the second " " from the left and remove everything left of that second " ". Thank you, if I can not find a more elegant solution, I will have to use Switch.